# Laptop-two hard drives-free upgrade to W10 will it invalidate the W7 drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I have a ThinkPad W520 .  It only holds one hard drive at a time.  It has Windows 7 Pro that came installed on it.  I also have a spare hard drive that also has Windows 7 Pro installed on it using the same key.  If I execute the free upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10, can I later remove the upgraded drive and put the Windows 7 drive back in?  Specifically, will my key be invalid on Windows 7 now?  I will only use one of the drives at a time, but I became concerned when I read that my key will be 'converted' to a Windows 10 key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the exact same situation last week.
Turns out the Windows 10 product is added to your key on the Microsoft systems.

You won't lose Windows 7 access by claiming your Win10 production upgrade entitlement.

That said, when you do want to go win10 in future with this device it will just work without needing to buy a licence key in future.

Comment: Point of Clarification:  When you accept the upgrade to Windows 10, you are not given a Windows 10 product key, you are only given a digital entitlement license. Any key that is displayed by any tool, which displays Windows license keys, is a generic key that is the same for eversyone using that particular version of Windows 10 (i.e. Home Single Language, Home, Professional).